# Are there any sample of elvish-like civilization being in their prime time

Tags: elves, fantasy-genre, science-fiction-genre

In a lot of SF and Fantasy work, there is a civilization being elven archetype.
I mean, civilization being in their fall, once powerful and full of magic or technology or sometimes both, now dying out. There are races such AS Elves from Tolkien or Sapkowski
 Minbari from *Babylon 5* and many more. I understand that, falling civilizations are more interesting from storytelling point of view.

Comment: Surely the Minbari were in their prime. No? They were the most technologically-powerful young race in the galaxy. The Vorlons were the all-powerful dying race (and somewhat responsible for the Minbari power). The technomages would make for an interesting side-question but, given your example, I'm struggling to figure out what you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking civ that isn't, well dying. Minbari were "loosing souls". They were powerful, but it wasn't their golden age

Comment: I see what you're saying, but that whole story was about the conflict between religious faith (that every Minbari is reincarnated) and scientific fact (that their were more Minbari dying than being born). Some might argue that the resolution of that conflict (in both physical and metaphysical terms) made them stronger than ever.

Comment: @pdr - The implication was that the Minbari were dramatically in decline. The height of their civilisation was nearly a thousand years before the start of the series.

Comment: @Richard: 1000 years earlier, they were "the oldest space-faring race" that weren't First Ones, but they were essentially Vorlon pawns. The implication is that, eventually, both Minbari and Human become the elder races of the galaxy (much like the Vorlons and Shadows had). So I'm not sure I can agree.

Comment: @pdr - It's not especially clear what happened to the Minbari after the Shadow war. Given how rapidly their birth-rate was declining, it's reasonable to assume they continued their slow journey into senescence. There's certainly no canon to indicate that they entered a new golden age.

Comment: @Richard: It has been stated as fact by JMS, though you're right that it was never in the series (http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/088.html JMS Speaks -- What about the other races). But even if you don't accept that future, the Minbari were certainly more advanced as a civilisation by the end of the series than they had been under Vorlon rule (fighting whomever they were told to fight, albeit in a perceived attempt to stop war).

Comment: That is close to what I though about Minbari. They made some big changes. Remember, the White Star-class ships. Minbar was really advanced, but their overall condition weren't to great, from what I recall. Still look at that one: [Space elves](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceElves)

Comment: @Demagog I see a couple of problems with your argument.  1.  Any civilization in its prime is a civilization that is about to fade.  If you're on top, it means that you're about to go down.  That's why we refer to Golden Ages in the past rather than the present.  A civilization's Golden Age is the period before it all fell apart.  2.  In The Lord of the Rings and The Hobbit, yes, the Elves are past their prime, but the Silmarillion describes the Elves' Golden Age, which took place primarily in Aman.  One could argue that their time in Beleriand was pretty good as well, despite the exile and...

Comment: @Demagog ...the Doom of Mandos.  They were very big fish in a fairly small pond.  No one in Middle-earth, aside from Ulmo, Sauron, Morgoth, and the few other Maiar and Valar who deigned to visit Middle-earth, were anywhere near as powerful and important as the Elves.  They built great cities and nations, ruled a respectable chunk of land, and shaped the world to their will.  Even the Eagles of Manwë answered to Elven Kings.

Comment: @Demagog: I'm not disagreeing that the Minbari were elf-like. They were the first thing that came to mind when you asked for an elf-like race who were in the ascendency. Which is why I was curious that you immediately discounted them. I think you're wrong that their overall condition wasn't great. They'd just fought a war against Earth with only one loss, and no one else had challenged them in a long time (no one challenged them even then; it was a miscommunication). And I couldn't think of another reason they'd be considered past their prime.

Comment: Justina Robson's "Chasing the dragon" has an elvish civilization at it's prime (but if you are looking for Tolkien-like elves you will probably not like Robson; this is somewhat cyber-punkish with elves in it).

Answer (score 4):

The Silmarillion by JRR Tolkien is a prequel to the Lord of the Rings. It chronicles the creation of Middle Earth, and the First and Second Ages. This time could be considered the elves' golden age, as they have many flourishing kingdoms such as Gondolin, and it was during the Second Age that the Rings of Power were forged by elven smiths working with Sauron.

Comment: added a little bit of substance, I'm looking for citations from elsewhere that would also help

Comment: Yes. I now about Silmarillion, I was just curious, if there are more similar works.

Comment: @Demagog - More of the same can be found in secondary texts, like Unfinished Tales and The History of Middle-earth.

Comment: I suppose "Elric Of Melnibone" stories could be the closest to what you're looking for. The Melniboneans are Elf-like, they are tall, willowy humanoids that possess magical and physical powers and dominate the world they live in, but cat-like in mind, as they delight in cruelty and sybaritic lifestyles, and rarely co-operate among themselves: Humans are playthings to them. However, as they are no longer curious, their society is on the way down -Not at their peak, then, but not yet a completely dying race. And they always *were* decadent in one sense.